# DC Roll For Starting a Fire?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, difficulty-class

A character wants to start a campfire in the woods. I assume this would be a Survival check, right?

But what would the DC check be? I've checked the entire Core Rulebook and can't find anything.

Comment: How are they trying to set a fire? Do they have an existing source of fire?

Comment: How do you do that? Do you use magic, tools, or your bare hands?

Comment: Just their bare hands. No magic or tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### All DC's are set by the GM.

This is included in the definition of Difficulty Class: **emphasis added**

> Whenever a creature attempts to perform an action whose success is not guaranteed, he must make some sort of check (usually a skill check). The result of that check must meet or exceed the Difficulty Class of the action that the creature is attempting to perform in order for the action to be successful. Climbing a slippery wall, dropping prone to avoid dragon breath, and gaining a suspicious guard’s trust all have their own **DCs that are determined by the GM. The higher the DC, the more difficult the challenge.**

If you're looking for guidance on where the DC should be, basically anybody can create a fire with the basic knowledge needed for adventuring. The DC is probably similar to or only slightly more than "Getting along in the wild.", DC 10. I would not make the DC more than 12, personally. This way a PC with high enough Wisdom or trained in Survival could get it by Taking 10.

Answer (score 4):

If they have an existing source of fire, like a [flint and steel](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/tools-kits/#TOC-Flint-and-Steel), it takes a full round action.

[Fire spreads rapidly,](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/environmental-rules/) per standard rules, so they don't need to do anything beyond that.

> Unchecked, fire tends to spread both rapidly and unpredictably.

If they lack appropriate tools, [a survival check](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/survival) sounds appropriate. It's a DC 10 check to provide food for yourself, and reasonably, I'd assume that includes cooking it.